# Adding an image to a google drawing using c#

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I'm using the [.NET client library](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html) and c# to try and add an image to a google drawing programmatically. I know I can upload a file and google can convert it to a drawing for me as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_drawings), but the only MIME type supported is .wmf and I need to upload a .jpg or other non-vector image file.

I don't need the drawing to be converted from a .jpg or anything; I simply want the same functionality as opening a new drawing and clicking on the image button to upload an image. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll say that it seems that with the current API, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing expects vector data, hence .wmf. You want to create a new document with an image in it.

This looks like a useful thread for your issue:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-documents-list-api/browse_thread/thread/0b50568304867b00/4ac28bda87889e8a?pli=1

Comment: I know I can upload an image into a document but I want to upload an image into a drawing. Like I said originally, I basically want to mimic opening a drawing and clicking on the image button.